# Not able to retrieve array from parse.com

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

i have made this array column in parse.com dashboard.i am  able to add values in the array from my app but m not able to get the array or list and using any function on it(even size() ) give null point exception on that line.

i have used many solutions but none worked.

my code where it is giving error.

```
real = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.realtext);
        fake = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.faketext);
        realbutton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.realbutton);
        fakebutton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fakebutton);
        real.setText(String.valueOf(news.getRealvote()));
        fake.setText(String.valueOf(news.getFake()));
fakebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                news.setuserArray(news.getAuthor().getUsername());
                List<ParseObject> a = news.getUserArray();


                Toast.makeText(c, a.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//any thing with a.size() etc anything gives error

                news.setFake();
                news.saveInBackground();
                fake.setText(String.valueOf(news.getFake()));

                realbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fakebutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
```

here is my getUserArray() method

```
public List<ParseObject> getUserArray() {

    return getList("users_rated");
}
```

the method to store data is working

```
public void setuserArray(String file) {
    addUnique("users_rated", file);
}
```

i have tried a lot but no success.plss help me retrieving the array.

are you asking for list adapter??

```
public class Customnewslistview extends ParseQueryAdapter<News> {

Context c;

public Customnewslistview(Context context) {
    super(context, "News");
    c = context;
}

@Override
public View getItemView(final News news, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (v == null) {
        final TextView real;
        final TextView fake;
        final ImageButton realbutton;
        final ImageButton fakebutton;
        final ProgressBar loader;
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.item_list_news_public, null);

        loader = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.eachnewsloder);

        ParseImageView newsImage = (ParseImageView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.icon);
        ParseFile photoFile = news.getParseFile("photo");
        if (photoFile != null) {
            newsImage.setParseFile(photoFile);
            newsImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                    Log.d("done pic", data.toString());
                    loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newsImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image40);
        }

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        titleTextView.setText(news.getTitle());
        // trying real fake buttons
        real = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.realtext);
        fake = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.faketext);
        realbutton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.realbutton);
        fakebutton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fakebutton);
        real.setText(String.valueOf(news.getRealvote()));
        fake.setText(String.valueOf(news.getFake()));
        realbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                news.setuserArray(news.getAuthor().toString());
                news.setRealvote();
                news.saveInBackground();
                real.setText(String.valueOf(news.getRealvote()));

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Cheating",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                realbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fakebutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        fakebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                news.setuserArray(news.getAuthor().getUsername());
                List<ParseObject> a=null;
                try {
                    a = news.fetchIfNeeded().getList("users_rated");
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                Toast.makeText(c, a.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                news.setFake();
                news.saveInBackground();
                fake.setText(String.valueOf(news.getFake()));

                realbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fakebutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        titleTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Dialog d = new Dialog(c);
                d.setContentView(R.layout.publicnewsdialog);
                d.setTitle("News");
                TextView text = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.dialogtext);
                text.setText(news.getTitle());
                // parsing image
                ParseImageView newsImage = (ParseImageView) d
                        .findViewById(R.id.dialogimage);
                ParseFile photoFile = news.getParseFile("photo");
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    newsImage.setParseFile(photoFile);
                    newsImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                            Log.d("done pic", data.toString());

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    newsImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image40);
                }
                d.show();

            }
        });
    }

    return v;
}

}
```

Comment: try `news.fetchIfNedded().getUserArray();`

Comment: giving error:   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 20:17:04.777: E/AndroidRuntime(7569): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParseObject has no data for this key.  Call fetchIfNeeded() to get the data.
12-06 20:17:04.777: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):  at com.parse.ParseObject.checkGetAccess(ParseObject.java:2793)
12-06 20:17:04.777: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):  at com.parse.ParseObject.getString(ParseObject.java:2351)
12-06 20:17:04.777: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):  at com.parse.ParseUser.getUsername(ParseUser.java:275)

Comment: show your `getList(String)` method

Comment: getList(String) is from parse.com api

Answer (score 2):

This is the method I use to get a `List` of a DB of `TrackedLocation` objects:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TrackedLocation"); 
query.whereEqualTo("imei", helpUtils.getDeviceIDEqualsIMEI());
query.setLimit(1000);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() 
{
    @Override
     public void done(List<ParseObject> dataList, ParseException e) {}
});
```

Do what you want with the `dataList` of `ParseObject`s you will receive on the `done` callback.

Comment: nahh..dat doesn't work...it gives me a list of all the rows with that specific vale..but here i want a array that is stored for each row differently..n i want to extract that array for each row in my adapter... @Emil Adz

Comment: then remove this line: query.whereEqualTo("imei", helpUtils.getDeviceIDEqualsIMEI());
and you will have the last 1000 entries in this table.