# How to retrive array in the right way?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

How can i retrive a array in the right way ?
I tried this :

```
    ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("test");
    List<String> list = parseObject.getList("arr");
```

but its not working so well , Im pretty sure its returns null ..
Any ideas ?

Comment: Does it return null, or doesn't it? Set a breakpoint, or test it with a `if` statement, or print out the value and see. There is no need to guess.

Comment: What does your query look like? I gave you this code in another question and you said it worked for you so it's not this.

Comment: @DavidConrad Its return null for sure ..
I checked .
The query :
http://prntscr.com/4qivpp

Comment: Is parseObject null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .it will work.it worked for me when i tested

```
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("test");
    query.whereExists("arr");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(e==null){

            for(int i=0; i<objects.size();i++){

                list=objects.get(i).getList("arr");

                Log.e("list",list.toString());
                    }
        }

        }
    });
```

Comment: OMG Thank you veery much , Works !

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TrackedLocation"); 
query.whereEqualTo("imei", helpUtils.getDeviceIDEqualsIMEI());
query.setLimit(1000);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() 
{
    @Override
     public void done(List<ParseObject> dataList, ParseException e) {}
});
```

Source : [Not able to retrieve array from parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426275/not-able-to-retrieve-array-from-parse-com)

Answer (score 0):

First you should check that the array which you want to retrieve is null or not.Following steps should be followed:

Step 1: declare a list for saving the retrieved array in this list

Step 2: check that the retrieved array is null or not

Step 2(a): if it is null assign null to list

Step 2(b): if not then you will get the desired value of the array

Programmatic Description:

```
    List<String>  ary_users  =  new ArrayList<String>();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("test");
     query.whereExists("arr");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> userList,
                ParseException e) {
            if (e==null) {
                if (userList.size()>0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
                        ParseObject p = userList.get(i);
                        if (p.getList("arr")!=null) {
                            ary_users =  p.getList("arr");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ary_users =  null;
                        }

                    }

                }


        }
    });
```